# Relation of variance and skewness for a skewed Gaussian variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I understand that skewness and variance are not inherently related, but given the type of distribution (in this case a skewed Gaussian distribution), can a relationship between the variance and Pearson's skewness factor $$E\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^3$$ be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consulting the side-bar of the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) we see that they express it with three parameters: $\xi$, $\omega$ and $\alpha$. If the parameter $\alpha$ is set to zero, the distribution reduces to $N(\xi,\omega^2)$ which of course has zero skew.

The variance is in terms of $\omega$ and $\alpha$ and the skew is in terms of $\alpha$ alone. So when you change $\alpha$ to increase or decrease the skew it does change the variance for fixed $\omega.$ However, you can always adjust $\omega$ to compensate to keep the variance fixed. So you can independently vary the skew and the variance and there is no fixed relationship between them.

Comment: I have a question though. For fixed omega, why does variance decrease as skewness decreases? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @paulinho Why would you expect it to be the other way around?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the comment. Doesn't it suggest that variance decreases as skewness increases$?

Comment: @paulinho No, as I said in the answer, skewness and variance can be varied independently. Just do a parameterization where instead of $\omega$ you use $\omega'^2 = \omega^2(1-\frac{2}{\pi}\delta^2).$ The PDF won't look as nice but two different parameters will have independent control over the variance and skew.

Comment: OK. I have one more question: in the first subsection of that Wiki page, it says that for a skewed Gaussian the maximum skewness that can be modeled is $\gamma_1=.9952717$. Do you know of any way to model distributions for which $\gamma_1>.9952717$?

Comment: @paulinho There are plenty of distributions that can have arbitrarily large skew. The lognormal comes to mind (but in this distribution since it only has two parameters, the variance *is* tied to the skew). Same goes for Pareto. In general you can get more skewed distributions by doing transformations (like the log normal is a transformation of a normal). There's the skew-t as well which can have larger skews. Which skewed distribution is the standard one to use for your application is probably best asked as a separate question and cross-validated might be a better forum than mathse.